# Como executar uma função N vezes em 1 segundo

Tags: javascript

Preciso executar uma função N vezes, porem oque eu fiz até agora não funcionou, lembrando que esse N vezes tem que ser distribuído igualmente por 1 segundo.

```
async function sendImage() {
    Console.log('teste');
}
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function demo() {
    while(true){
        sendImage();
        await sleep(1000/60);
    }
}

demo();
```

Comment: Não, é javascript puro.

Answer (score 1):

Por que não passar o valor "N vezes" na função `demo()`, desta forma:

```
demo(5); // executar função 5 vezes em 1 segundo
```

E na função `demo()` receber e dividir esse valor em 1000, que equivale a 1 segundo:

```
async function demo(n) {
    while(true){
        sendImage();
        await sleep(1000/n);
    }
}
```

Ficaria assim:

```js
async function sendImage() {
    console.log('teste');
}
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function demo(n) {
    while(true){
        sendImage();
        await sleep(1000/n);
    }
}

demo(5); // 5 vezes em 1 segundo
```

> Como observado, o correto é `console.log` (tudo minúsculo), senão o
>   script para de rodar.

Comment: Como eu tinha dito, meu código não funciona, por exemplo, usando o código que você disponibilizou na resposta, coloquei para fazer 60 vezes por segundo, porem como pode ver nessa imagem i.stack.imgur.com/dtLmh.png o tempo entre cada console.log é diferente.
Como eu coloquei 60, seria 1000/60 = 16.6666...., ou seja, a cada 16.6666 milissegundos era para ter um console.log, mas isso não acontece com meu código.
Justamente esse meu problema, preciso que isso seja preciso em milissegundos.

Comment: @LucasCarezia Entendi. Vou ver aqui...

Comment: Agora eu peguei. Acredito que a precisão em tempo vai ser definido pela resolução da Promise :p nesse caso um `setInterval` possa ser mais recomendado.

Comment: @LucasCarezia Trabalhar com valores muito baixos no setTimeout não é garantia de precisão. Fiz o teste do código em 3 navegadores diferentes (Chrome, FF e Opera) e cada um mostra um valor diferente de processamento, apesar de aproximados. O que isso quer dizer? Que valores muito baixos de intervalo (milionésimos de segundo), depende muito da capacidade de processamento do computador, e o navegador não consegue processar isso de forma exata. Veja, testei 60 processamentos em 4 segundos... (continua)

Comment: @LucasCarezia ... que seria 4*60 = 240... no Chrome processou 226, no FF 227 e no Opera 232... Isso, sem falar que em cada F5 o valor às vezes muda... Concluindo, acho que não tem como processar isso de forma precisa, vai processar sempre um valor aproximado...

Comment: @LucasCarezia Se o cara tem um computador ruim, vai processar bem menos ainda. Isso pq meu PC é rápido, e mesmo assim não processa tudo.

Comment: Tudo bem, vou abrir uma nova pergunta, dizendo o meu problema completo para ver se encontra uma solução melhor do que estou tendo agora.

Comment: @LucasCarezia Criei uma página de teste, se quiser testar em vários navegadores verá o que estou falando: http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/processa.php

Comment: https://jsperf.com/

Comment: @LucasCosta A página não abre... fica carregando e termina com erro 500

Comment: Aqui tb @dvd, provavel que o servidor esta com problemas (primeira vez que vejo isso). Mas em outro momento teste o jsperf.com, se vc nao conhece, conseguimos testar a performance entre scripts nele.

Comment: @LucasCosta Blz... vou esperar um tempo e tentar de novo

Answer (score 0):

Para chegar a 1 segundo precisa passar os milissegundos, que é igual à 1000.

```js
async function sendImage(i) {
    console.log('teste ' + Math.random());
}
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function demo() {
    while(true){
        sendImage();
        await sleep(1000);
    }
}

demo();
```

*PS: Tinha um erro em `Console.log`, o correto é `console.log`*